# Is $C=ADA^{-1}$ with $D$ diagonal and $A$ invertible the unique eigendecomposition of $C$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider an $m\times m$ matrix $C$ that can be expressed as $C=ADA^{-1}$  where

1. $D$ is an $m\times m$ diagonal matrix with distinct finite nonzero elements,
2. $A$ is an $m\times m$ invertible matrix.

   > **Statement:** It follows that $ADA^{-1}$ is the unique eigen-decomposition of $C$, up to a right multiplication of $A$ by an invertible diagonal matrix and up to a certain reordering of the diagonal elements of $D$.

Is this an obvious statetement? Could you give me a reference for it?

Comment: Since $CA=AD$ it follows that column $j$ of $A$ is an eigenvector of $C$ with eigenvalue $D_{jj}$. The ordering of the columns in $A$ does not affect this observation. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: I am asking for a reference on: if we find two matrices $E,F$ with $F$ diagonal and invertible and $E$ invertible such that $C=EFE^{-1}$, then it should be that (i) by appropriate rearranging the order of the main diagonal elements of $F$, $D=F$ and (ii) by applying the same order to the columns of $E$, it should be that $E=AQ$ with $Q$ diagonal and invertible.

Comment: I think that is pretty much implied by my previous comment. If you are looking for a written reference, I would recommend Horn and Johnson, Matrix Analysis, Theorem 1.3.7 an onwards (second edition).